# Style PreferenceFragmentCompat like PreferenceFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-theme, android-styles, preferencefragment

In my application, I had first created `PreferenceFragment` using no support libraries as such:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Display the fragment as the main content.
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    PrefsFragment mPrefsFragment = new PrefsFragment();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, mPrefsFragment);
    mFragmentTransaction.commit();

}

public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_screen);
    }
}
```

But then I decided to use the support libraries, as I've been using support fragments all over the app and thought this will be more consistent

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Display the fragment as the main content.
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    PrefsFragment mPrefsFragment = new PrefsFragment();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, mPrefsFragment);
    mFragmentTransaction.commit();

}

public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_screen, rootKey);
    }
}
```

and add in the style file, as it doesn't work without me

```
<item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
```

[Here's what the PreferenceFragmentCompat looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K4pW.png)

[And PreferenceFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vVWi.png)

Is it possible to get the same style in the `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, doesn't seem like I changed much but got totally different styles.

Also, one more question? Does that affect all my fragments? I never used the non-support fragments so I don't know if I'm missing on a much better style if I ignored the support fragments.

Edit Update: The solution was change the preferenceTheme item to `@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material` instead

Comment: What about using [`android.support.v14.preference.PreferenceFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v14/preference/PreferenceFragment.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I tried this (except changing the parent as I need an actionbar, and item name is still preferenceFragment), while the style is very close to the original, for some reason all of them are tabbed (there is a huge space before each item), especially the last item which is child item, is basically tabbed after the half the screen, can I remove that somehow?

Comment: Seems this is an issue with PreferenceFragmentCompat in general, even the previous theme had tabs, much smaller, but still there

Comment: See whether applying `<item name="listPreferredItemPaddingStart">0dp</item>` and `<item name="listPreferredItemPaddingEnd">0dp</item>` to the theme somehow affects.

Comment: used PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material instead and it gave me a very close result to the original, thank you

Comment: @newRuser, in your edit to your question you mentioned that you have changed `preferenceTheme` attribute, but in my answer the attribute is `preferenceFragmentCompatStyle`. Which one is correct?

Comment: Apologies, fixed both the parent and item name